# Calling a custom action from power apps component

Tags: javascript, typescript, dynamics-crm, powerapps

I am trying to create a component that makes a post request to a custom action in my environment. This action has an input called `leadid` and an output called `data`, and when called triggers a custom plugin. However, I am having trouble trying to figure out how to call this action from my component.

I understand that you can make calls using `this._context.webAPI.retrieveMultipleRecords(entity, query)` but I am not trying to achieve this.

I have tried the following directly in the console (in the browser) and it works perfectly, but I get an error `Xrm is not defined` when using the same code in my TypeScript file:

```
fetch(Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.2/dev_GetData", {
    "method":"POST",
    "headers":{
        "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "OData-MaxVersion": "4.0",
            "OData-Version": "4.0"
    },
    "body": JSON.stringify({
        "leadid": "7ba18ae0-4d0e-ea11-a813-000d3a1bbd52"
    })
}).then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
})
```

I find this odd as when I hover over the other parts (page, context, getClientUrl), it gives me the details of what It does.

What might I be doing wrong, or how may I get the client url without using Xrm.page...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Managed solution/Additional Tool for Dataverse which will give you code snippet with actual values for webapi call.
Tool is [Dataverse Rest Builder](https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB)

https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/GuidoPreite.DRB/

Example code snippet for Lead qualification Action

```
var execute_QualifyLead_Request = {
        // Parameters
        entity: { entityType: "lead", id: "524a9e0b-f3e6-e711-80e9-005056936c69" }, // entity
        CreateAccount: true, // Edm.Boolean
        CreateContact: true, // Edm.Boolean
        CreateOpportunity: true, // Edm.Boolean
        Status: 1, // Edm.Int32
    
        getMetadata: function () {
            return {
                boundParameter: "entity",
                parameterTypes: {
                    entity: { typeName: "mscrm.lead", structuralProperty: 5 },
                    CreateAccount: { typeName: "Edm.Boolean", structuralProperty: 1 },
                    CreateContact: { typeName: "Edm.Boolean", structuralProperty: 1 },
                    CreateOpportunity: { typeName: "Edm.Boolean", structuralProperty: 1 },
                    Status: { typeName: "Edm.Int32", structuralProperty: 1 }
                },
                operationType: 0, operationName: "QualifyLead"
            };
        }
    };
    
    Xrm.WebApi.online.execute(execute_QualifyLead_Request).then(
        function success(response) {
            if (response.ok) { return response.json(); }
        }
    ).then(function (responseBody) {
        var result = responseBody;
        console.log(result);
        // Return Type: Collection(mscrm.crmbaseentity)
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    });


  [1]: https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB
```